# How can I get text encoding system explicitly in Qt?

Tags: qt, encoding

It's easy to turn a string into a `QTextCodec *` by the following:

```
char *str = "UTF-8";
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName(str);
```

But can we do the inverse? For example:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("System");
```

But how can I turn `codec` into a string so that I know the encoding system is UTF-8/UTF-16 or others?

Comment: Surely the inverse would be `QString name = QTextCodec::NameForCodec(codec);`?  Are you just trying to get the codec for the current locale?

Comment: @cmannett85 Is this a new method of Qt 5? I didn't see `NameForCodec` in Qt4 documentation.

Comment: Err.. It doesn't exist, I was pointing out that your inverse example wasn't really an inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I turn codec into a string so that I know the encoding system is UTF-8/UTF-16 or others?

By using `QTextCodec::name() const`.

```
char *str = "UTF-8";
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName(str);
QByteArray name = codec->name(); //  "UTF-8"
```

Comment: Ah~I got your point. It works for me. But if I feed `codecForName()` with "System" rather than an explicit string like "UTF-8", it returns only "System"... Can qt tell me what exactly it is?

Comment: @wlnirvana Are you just trying to get the codec for the current locale?

Comment: Basically yes. I came across this problem when I tried to get system codec. But when I tried to solve it, I wondered whether there is a general method to do so.

Comment: @wlnirvana There isn't a general method, the `QTextCodec` returned by `QTextCodec::codecForLocale()` has a fixed name of "System" - but that is the codec for the current locale.

Comment: Ah...I see. So what would be the method to get the locale codec explicitly? Say how can I know whether the system is using ASCII/UTF-8/UTF-16?

Comment: Qt doesn't know because it queries a 3rd-party library - read this conversation: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.user/5022